# how can i analyse what is happening when my code hangs

Tags: psql

when i execute the code below it executes the alter table command then hangs. any idea why this happens appreciated also is it possible to execute on a line by line basis to see where the problem is.

```
alter table subscription_kits
add column first_subscription_kit_redemption DATE;

update subscription_kits

SET first_subscription_kit_redemption = c_e.updated_at
FROM
        customer_events c_e
WHERE
type = 'redeemed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is simply too slow. It could be slow to read or slow to write. Without additional information, such as table structures, data sizes and the existence or nonexistence of further checks and triggers as well as data about server load, I can only provide you general hints in this answer.

First of all, you are loading data from `customer_events` in order to update your `first_subscription_kit_redemption` to `updated_at`. We do not see what your `customer_events` table is looking alike, but, your query does not select a single record from `customer_events` per your `first_subscription_kit_redemption`, but all of the records. If `customer_events` may have multiple records whose `type` is redeemed, then you will probably need to enhance your `where` clause with further criteria.

Also, these may be very large tables, which could also explain the slowness you have experienced. Try running

```
select updated_at
from customer_events
where type = 'redeemed'
```

and you will need to determine whether it's appropriate for your RDBMS to go through all the records of `subscription_kits` and to update the `first_subscription_kit_redemption` value of each and every one of them to each and every `updated_at` result from the query above. If not, which is the probable case, then you have a problem with the logic that's being executed and you will need to apply fixes on your criteria.

Furthermore, you may want an index on the `type` field if it's being frequently searched for. Also, if the `type` field can only have enumerable values and it's a `varchar` at this point, then you might want to change the type to an enum, so your search will convert into a numeric search rather than a slow text-based search.